# Arrow in RStudio Windows -- "Error: NotImplemented: Support for codec 'snappy' not built"

Tags: r

I am working on RStudio Pro Server (Windows) with the Arrow package to manipulate big parquet datasets. I've installed arrow, but much of the functionality is limited by a lack of support for snappy. I've already tried the fixes suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64937524/r-arrow-error-support-for-codec-snappy-not-built). I contacted the computer science department, which manages the server, and they installed arrow for me and also installed snappy systemwide. Still no dice. When I try to use the read_parquet() or collect() functions, I get back some version of this error:

`Error: NotImplemented: Support for codec 'snappy' not built. In order to read this file, you will need to reinstall arrow with additional features enabled. Set one of these environment variables before installing: * LIBARROW_MINIMAL=false (for all optional features, including 'snappy') * ARROW_WITH_SNAPPY=ON (for just 'snappy') See https://arrow.apache.org/docs/r/articles/install.html for details`

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, I had the same problem right now. I took the final remark form your link and it worked for me. It said: "Sys.setenv(ARROW_S3="ON")
Sys.setenv(NOT_CRAN="true")
install.packages("arrow", repos = "https://arrow-r-nightly.s3.amazonaws.com")"